# CardIO (iOS Xcode), receiving a link error for __udivmodsi4 :

Tags: ios, xcode, card.io

After bringing CardIO (iOS XCode) into my build, I am receiving a link error for __udivmodsi4

Here are some specifics re my environment:

- Compiler Version GCC 4.2
- XCode v 3.2.5,  iOS SDK 4.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using card.io requires Xcode 4.x. This is because old Xcode version use an older compiler version, which doesn't provide support for `__udivmodsi4`.